# Is it possible to render an image stored in laravel storage while in development mode?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm working on a web app using `React` and `Laravel` which are in separate projects, I'm trying to render an image fetched from `Laravel` storage in an `img` tag using the URL I'm getting for example `/storage/file-name.png`

this is my show method:

```
  public function show(Patient $patient)
    {
        $this->response = new stdClass();
        ...My code

        $this->response->image =  Storage::url($patient->user->image);

        ...My code
        return response()->json($this->response, $this->successStatus)->header('content-type', 'application/json');
    }
```

and in my react app I'm passing the URL to the component the contains the `img` tag as a props but nothing shows. I tried adding `http://localhost:8000` to the `/storage/file-name.png` and result is the same.

P.S: i console logged the `image` prop and it's returning `/storage/file-name.png` which is correct.

here is my dropzone component render method:

```
render() {
    const { isHighLight } = this.state;
    const { isMultiple, isEnabled, title, image } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={classNames({
          dropzone: true,
          'dropzone--disbaled': !isEnabled,
          'dropzone--highlight': isHighLight
        })}
        role='presentation'
        onClick={this.handleDropzoneClick}
        onDragLeave={this.handleDragLeave}
        onDragOver={this.handleDragOver}
        onDrop={this.handleDrop}
      >
        <img src={image} alt='dropzone' className='dropzone__img' />
        <input ref={this.fileInputRef} type='file' className='dropzone__input' multiple={isMultiple} onChange={this.handleFileUploaded} />
        <span className='dropzone__title'>{title}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Is there a way to show an image while in development mode? Or should I host my app somewhere in order to be able to show the images?

Comment: You need to provide a better example, there’s missing code here relating to the React application. Please read through [How To Create A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please provide some front side codes. and also did you create symbolic link ?

Comment: sounds like it's more of an issue with your virtual host setup. You'll need to setup a virtual host for both codebases.

Comment: I updated the question @rhys_stubbs

Comment: @Juakali92 yes i thought about it but i didn't where to start

Comment: @alihussein Can you open/view that image in your browser by navigating to the URL?

Comment: What's your setup, xampp and windows?

Comment: @rhys_stubbs yes, it's returning a message that says resource not found but the image is still inside the storage directory

Comment: @Juakali92 Im using LAMP stack and Linux

Comment: So you *cant* access that image, as that sounds like a 404. Not to be condescending but you sound inexperienced, but suggestion is to work out how to properly setup your environment and whether that is the problem or whether it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end application doesn't have permission to see the file in your storage path for default.

You can try to convert your file in base64:

```
public function getFile(string $name)
{
    if (file_exists("storage/{$name}")) {
        return base64_encode(file_get_contents("storage/{$name}"));
    }
}
```

front-end:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, base64 code here">
```